# JOptionPane run not working

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm working on a program and I don't understand what's wrong with the program, I've tried to make it work, but every time I would run it and put in an answer, it adds a zero to the answer. Help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Furniture
{
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
       String response_1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type of Table - 1)Pine Wood, 2)Oak, 3)Mahogany");
       int type_of_wood = Integer.parseInt(response_1);
      String response_2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Size of table - 4)Small, or 5)Large");
      int size = Integer.parseInt(response_2);
      int price_of_wood = 0;
      int price_of_table = 0;
       switch(type_of_wood)
      {

       case 1:
          price_of_wood = 100;
          break;

       case 2:
          price_of_wood = 225;
          break;

       case 3:
          price_of_wood = 310;
          break;

      case 4:
         price_of_table = 0;
         break;

      case 5:
         price_of_table = 35;
         break;

       default:
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Number entered.");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The price is " + price_of_wood + price_of_table + " dollars");
    }
}
```

Comment: `"The price is " + price_of_wood + price_of_table + " dollars"` that might be the problem. your integers are kind of "added" in the output. try with `"The price is " + price_of_wood += price_of_table + " dollars"`. it might solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use variable like `int`, `float` etc. with `String` in `println()` for showing output they gets concatenated instead of getting added or whatever operation you try to do. So first evaluate your expression which is to output. Try this,

```
 int price = price_of_wood + price_of_table;
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The price is " + price + " dollars");
```

Comment: I'm also having problems so that it isn't reading case 5 properly? would you know this by any chance? What I mean by not reading it properly is that it would not read the number.

Comment: you are using `type_of_wood` variable even for case 5. `type_of_wood` will never be `5` if input is done correctly. try using two `switch` one for `type_of_wood` and other for `size`.

Comment: @GeneralWolf if this solved your problem accurately mark it as accepted so that others will also follow this answer. and thanks